# Symfony 5 setting EventSubscriber-priority

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently having trouble setting the priority of a eventsubscriber to set the locale depending on a query parameter.

This is my entry in my services.yaml:

```
App\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, priority: 101 }
```

As shown by the symfony doc I issued:

```
debug:event kernel.request
```

Which shows me that the Subscribers priority remains at 20.
This is confirmed by my app's behaviour.

Comment: You are building an Event Listener, or an Event Subscriber? They are both Event Dispatcher related, but they are not the same thing, and are configured differently.

Comment: I am building an EventSubscriber.

Comment: Then you do not need to tag it at all, and you can configure it directly from the subscriber code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber)

Example:

```php
class SampleEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 9999] // 9999 is priority
        ];
    }

    public funtion onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $request) {
        // all logic on requests
    }
}
```

then register this subscriber in `services.yaml`

```yaml
services:
    App\Events\SampleEventSubscriber:
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', method: 'onKernelRequest' }
```

Comment: Actually you can set a priority with a listener just fine.  And think about the service definition in your answer.  The whole point of a subscriber (vs listener) is that you don't need any tags in the definition.  Hmmm.